# Return HTML tag value in Java

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to write java code that will return the value in a HTML tag in java.  below is the method I been trying to get working.. can someone please help me out

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.seoreport.exceptions.DataNotFoundException;

public class utils {

    public String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException
    {
        String value = null;

        String searchFor = "/<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\\/" + tag + "\\>/";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inHTML);

        return value;

    }

}
```

Comment: This question might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use regex for this, instead of using a HTML parser like http://jsoup.org/ ? Regexes are not well suited to this task.

Comment: @derekerdmann: thats the answer ;)

Comment: RegExp is a very, very poor choice for an HTML parser.

Comment: Ignore these people: they are talking about parsing an entire HTML file of unknown contents that can do every possible whacky thing, which while very tricky is almost never needed. For canned HTML snippets, **regexes are optimal:** that's why we use search and replace in our text editors. See [this answer on matching HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) for a more completist approach, but simpler solutions are often perfectly adequate. Can't tell what you actually need here though.

Comment: Here's the grammar for a tag: `tag: start_tag tag_name (whitespace any_nv_pair) * end_tag`. The hard part is the `any_nv_pair` production; that’s `any_nv_pair: name whitespace* "=" value`, where `value` is `value: quoted_value | unquoted_value`, and the simplest regex for `quoted_value` is `(?<quote> ['"] ) (?: (?! \k<quote> ) . ) * \k<quote>` (in `/sx` mode, of course). You have to write grammars for these things, because HTML is defined by a grammar. [See my longer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491).

Comment: i need to get this working i am going to have to search for other stuff too.. thats why

Answer (score 1):

why don't yo try to use an XML parser and access to the block using xpath? you may do something like:

```
// Parse the XML file and build the Document object in RAM
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(fileName));

// Normalise text representation.
// Collapses adjacent text nodes into one node.
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

// get tag
xpath = ".//*/"+yourTag;
NodeList content= XPathAPI.selectNodeList(doc, xpath);
```

doing in this way you will have all the content in the content variable.

you can use it as a text using:

```
content.tostring();
```

Comment: You are assuming that the document is an XHTML document. This will not work for normal HTML.

Comment: I admit i did not try it on standard HTML in Java. I did it in python using minidom and was working fine for me. Give it a shot and observe the behaviour.

Comment: i need to get this working i am going to have to search for other stuff too.. thats why